# How to add a loading icon while searching a vuejs list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have to render a list of over 3000 lessons, these lessons need to be searched through. [Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the basics of what I'm doing with the sample data](https://jsfiddle.net/everlessdrop/zfLmegqo/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">  
<div id="filter-by-example" class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <input class="col s4" v-model="searchQuery">
</div>
    <ul class="collection col s4">
      <li class="collection-item" v-for="n in lessons| filterBy searchQuery in 'name'">
        {{ n.name }} 
        <a href="#l.id" class="secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var lessons = { /*Sample data*/ }    

new Vue({
  el: '#filter-by-example',
  data: {
    lessons: lessons
  }
});
```

In the fiddle you should be able to see how there is some lag while searching, this as much worse in production as there's more styling, and event binding on each list item.

I want to know how to show a loading icon while vue.js does the search, if this is even possible. I've looked around and I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make use of [terminal directive](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#terminal). How do you feel about using limitBy? Limiting your list to, say, 50 elements would drastically increase performance because of rendering time saved.